# Set AWS profile_name with pynamodb

Tags: python, database, amazon-web-services, orm, amazon-dynamodb

The PynamoDB documentation says that "PynamoDB uses botocore to interact with the DynamoDB API. Thus, any method of configuration supported by botocore works with PynamoDB." (http://pynamodb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/awsaccess.html)

With boto I am able to specify a profile_name for local development. Like this:

```
import boto3

session = boto3.Session(profile_name='name-of-profile')
dynamodb_client = session.client('dynamodb')
```

I can't figure out how to accomplish the same thing with PynamoDB. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [the `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html#shared-credentials-file).

The `PynamoDB` docs [also state that using env variables](http://pynamodb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/awsaccess.html) for local development is recommended:

> For local development the use of environment variables such as AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY is probably preferable

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was aware of that option but I was more familiar with the named profile option. For now I will just set the environment variables in my virtual_env activation and unset them in deactivation. I'd still like to know if the named profile option is possible and if so, then how. Thanks, again.